# Printing Parsed Bison Expression

Tags: bison

How can we get the final parsed expression from bison?

ex:

```
A + B > C
```

Where A, B, and C are all integers properly parsed, would print out

```
10 + 5 > 14
```

Ive tried to patch into the YY_SYMBOL_PRINT macro and the YYDPRINT but i couldn't get what i want. The trace would print out everything including the parser's states.

Can this be done somehow, or should i manually add every token as its parsed to a resulting string in my output union?

Comment: can't you add a print statements to your grammar rules and wouldn't that work?

Comment: Nope, I need access to it after parsing is complete, it doesn't have to be printed, maybe stored for later checking

Comment: then global variable and concatenation will be the ones to help you

Comment: why not store it in a data structure like tree If you need them after wards. They would be certainly the better representation

Comment: You need to (i) build an expression tree while parsing and (ii) have a means of printing the expression tree.